# Eclipse add XText editor to perspective

Tags: java, eclipse, rcp, xtext

I have my own perspective to which I want to add the Xtext generated editor at a special location.

Currently, it opens at the editor area (hard coded into Eclipse as `org.eclipse.ui.editorss`). However, the Xtext editor should open at a special location and not at the editor area. Normally you achieve this behavior by either adding the view direct or by adding a placeholder with the ID of the view.
The generated Xtext editor is not a view and thus cannot be added using the view mechanisms.

I prefer the way with plugin.xml's `perspectiveExtensions` extension.

How can I add the Xtext editor at my very own location to my perspective?

Comment: Editors are always shown in the editor area, there is no way to change this.

Comment: You can create an embedded editor and place it anywhere. See http://de.slideshare.net/meysholdt/lightweight-xtext-editorsasswtwidgets

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In an Eclipse 3.x compatibility mode RCP editors are always shown in the editor area, there is no way to change this.